# Use $I++ more than once in a loop

Tags: php

I need to use the value for $i++ in numerous places but if I do that then some fields end up skipping values and instead of being 1, 2, 3 etc. they are 1, 3, 5 and the other field has values of 2, 4, 6 etc.

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>
<?php while (have_rows( 'something' ) ): the_row(); ?>
 <div>This number: <?php echo $i++; ?></div>
 <div>Should be the same as this one:  <?php echo $i++; ?></div>
<?php end while; ?>
```

It works if I create another variable but this feels like a hack.

```
<?php $i = 1;
      $x = 1;
?>
<?php while (have_rows( 'something' ) ): the_row(); ?>
 <div>This number: <?php echo $i++; ?></div>
 <div>Should be the same as this one:  <?php echo $x++; ?></div>
<?php end while; ?>
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I am not sure what is the question here, probably you don't understand how the increment operator works. Every time you use it the value of the variable is incremented. If you want to increment it once in each iteration then you must use it only once somewhere inside your loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the increment as a discrete step at the end of the loop, this means you can use it in various places without wondering when you changed the value...

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>
<?php while (have_rows( 'something' ) ): 
     the_row(); ?>
     <div>This number: <?php echo $i; ?></div>
     <div>Should be the same as this one:  <?php echo $i; ?></div>
     <?php $i++; ?>
<?php end while; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution is simple - increase `$i` only **once**:

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>
<?php while (have_rows( 'something' ) ): the_row(); ?>
 <div>This number: <?php echo $i; ?></div>
 <div>Should be the same as this one:  <?php echo $i++; ?></div>
<?php end while; ?>
```

Comment: I need them to match though. For example if I have tabs. The tab id should = 1 and the tab content should = 1. The second tab should be 2 and 2. Does your code do this?

Comment: So run it and see, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

A clean approach would be to echo the value of `$i` in your loop, and only increase it at the end, as a step alone. This is a good approach to have not only in PHP but in programming in general.

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>
<?php while (have_rows( 'something' ) ): the_row(); ?>
 <div>This number: <?php echo $i; ?></div>
 <div>Should be the same as this one:  <?php echo $i; ?></div>
<?php 
    $i++;
end while; ?>
```